# error in passing 2-d array to function

Tags: c++, algorithm

The program is just for passing complete 2-d array to function.I am able to run the problem by hook or by crook but i didnt understood.I have written a program which i should have written threotically and which i have written to make it working(in comments) 
can anyone please explain me this issue??

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
void print(bool *a);
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bool arr[3][3]={1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1};
    print(arr[0]);//**This IS working but why  we need subscript 0 here only print(arr) should work?..**
    getch();
    return 0;
}
void print(bool *a)
{

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                cout<<*(a+i*3+j)<<"|";//**cant we use cout<<a[i][j] here??In 1 d array it is working fine**
            }
            cout<<"--";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void print(bool *a)
```

should be

```
void print(bool a[][3])
```

the compiler needs to know the size of second dimension in order to compute offset for addressing.

```
void print(bool a[][3], int rowSize)
{
   for(int i=0;i<rowSize;i++)
   {
     for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
     {
        cout<<a[i][j]<<"|";
     }
     cout<<"--";
}
```

In C++, you should prefer using `vector<vector <bool> >` over 2D dynamic array `arr`.

Comment: can't we parse only the base address(pointer) to pass whole 2-D array??

Comment: @AmanJagga this way we are passing only the base address, however, since it is a 2D array, internally it it stored as 1d, so only specify the base address is not enough, you have to specify the second dimension size in order for compiler to to addressing, that's why the size of second dimension is required to known

Comment: then can you explain how the above program(program posted by me with question) is working fine? Moreover i didn't understand how we are passing base address in your way?we havent used pointer then how base address is passed??

Comment: @AmanJagga sorry for late reply, I was distracted by other stuff. arrays are internally decayed to pointers, so even syntax wise, we did not use a pointer, internally, it is still a pointer. accessing array element a[i][j] is equivalent to *(a+i*3+j) if you know second dimension size is 3. This link may be helpful for you to understand the topic: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
 void print(bool a[][3])
```

which is the correct prototype if you want to call `print(arr);`

Then you can use `a[i][j]` to access array elements in the `print` function body.

`arr` is an array of array `3` of `bool` and when passed to `print` function call the `arr` expression is converted to a pointer to an array `3` of `bool`.

Comment: but then why in 1 D array we can use a[i] to access array when we had only passed the base address in func?? example of this is#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
void print(int *a);
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[3]={1,2,3};
    print(arr);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
void print(int *a)
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i];
    }
}